# Making Perl script *run itself* with flags

Tags: perl, flags

I'm very new to Perl, and have recently encountered the following problem.
My Perl code must all reside within a single file (it's being called by another program I have no control of).
I now wish to make the script run with a flag (e.g., `perl myscript.pl -T` for taint mode), although it is initially called without the flag. How can I do that, i.e., how do I "set the flag" from within the Perl file?

One idea that I've had is to make the file launch itself again (after being called without flags), this time with the `-T` flag (by issuing a shell command such as `system($^X, "myscript.pl -T", @ARGS);`). Would that work? Any better ideas?

Comment: if you control `myscript.pl` you can set taint mode by altering your shebang line to include `-T` e.g. `#!/usr/bin/env perl -T`

Comment: What command is used to invoke the script in the other program? If it's something like `/path/to/myscript.pl`, you can simply add `-T` to the shebang line.

Comment: a `-T` in the shebang line doesn't necessarily enable taint mode -- if the script is invoked with `perl` from the shell without `-T`, you get a fatal error

Comment: Still, putting `-T` in the shebang is the simplest solution.  It'll either work or your script won't start, telling you to try a more complex workaround.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, unfortunately I have no control over the program that invokes my script, otherwise it would've been too easy and not too interesting :)

Comment: @mike622867 That's not what I said. I asked how the *other* program invokes your script. If it calls `/path/to/myscript.pl` from a shell, for example, you can add `-T` to the shebang line in `myscript.pl` to enable taint mode; if it calls `perl /path/to/myscript.pl`, for example, adding `-T` to the shebang line will cause an error as mob points out.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're on the right track. You can make use of the [`$^{TAINT}`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlvar#TAINT) variable, and `exec` instead of `system`:

```
exec($^X, $0, '-T', @ARGV) if $^{TAINT} < 1;
```

This won't work in all cases. For one thing, you'll lose some other command line switches that your script might initially be called with:

```
perl -I/path/to/some/more/libs -w -MNecessary::Module myscript.pl ...
```

There are some workarounds to some of these (`use warnings` or add `-w` switch to your `exec` statement above, analyze [`@INC`](http://metacpan.org/pod/perlvar#INC) and [`%INC`](http://metacpan.org/pod/perlvar#INC1) to determine what `-I` and `-M` switches were added) but the more you can learn about exactly how your script is called, the more you can figure out what workarounds you need to worry about.

---

Depending on the ... group dynamics in play here, another approach is to exercise some indirect control of the calling program. Go ahead and put `-T` on the shebang line as @Hunter McMillen and @ThisSuitIsBlackNot suggest, wait for a bug report, and then diagnose the problem as "program not invoked with -T switch" ...

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work for me, most likely due to the issues you've mentioned.

Putting the -T on the shebang line produces the following error:
_"-T" is on the #! line, it must also be used on the command line_